# How to use the IBandClient addtileasync method within an mvvm project such as template10 Minimal

Tags: microsoft-band

The addtileasync method on the BandClient opens a modal dialog asking permission to install the tile on the Microsoft Band. But in an mvvm application like Template10 the dialog is not presented and the tile is not added. How would this method be implemented given an mvvm implementation?

Comment: I burned an MSDN trouble call on this. The answer I received was that the Band SDK was not supported and advised to come here.

Comment: I've tried running this code in a user control on the view and it continues to fail.

Comment: I've managed to navigate to a custom page that will allow the SDK to present the user auth dialog when adding a tile. The challenge is now getting back to the mvvm implementation. 
`
Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame; 
if (rootFrame == null) 
{ 
   rootFrame = new Frame(); 
   Window.Current.Content = rootFrame; 
} 
if (rootFrame.Content == null) 
{ 
   rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(AddBandTilePage)); 
} 
Window.Current.Activate();`

Comment: Can anyone on the band dev team tell me specifically how is that modal dialog implemented within the await bandClient.TileManager.AddTileAsync(tile) call? If I can duplicate that dialog I can probably get help from the template10 team.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem...I'm using Caliburn Micro without Template10, but I believe the overall architecture is similar. As best as I can determine, that popup is implemented by assuming that Window.Current is a Frame which it tries to grab, navigate to the auth dialog and then navigate back after the user approves. I tried several approaches and the one that currently works for me (although a complete kludge that I'm not thrilled with) is to inject a Frame as you mention above. However, before doing so, I copy my ShellView into a public property on App so that I can go back to it after adding the tile. My code looks basically like this:

When I need to add the Tile (on a Setting View):

```
        ((App)Application.Current).ShellHolder = Window.Current.Content;

        Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
        if (rootFrame == null)
        {
            rootFrame = new Frame();
            Window.Current.Content = rootFrame;
        }

        rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(BandAddTileView));
        Window.Current.Activate();
```

Then, in the BandTileView when it's logic is wrapped up, I call something like this:

```
    private void ResetShell(BandTileResult result) {
        var app = (App)Application.Current;
        if (app == null) return;

        app.TileResult = result;

        Window.Current.Content = (UIElement)app.ShellHolder;
        Window.Current.Activate();
    }
```

I then have some logic in when ShellView comes back in play that navigates back to the Settings View and deals with the BandTileResult.

Like I said, it's a kludge and not entirely elegant but it seems to working OK and with a little styling on the BandAddTileView it presents a pretty good user experience for the app user.

Any feedback from the band dev team would definitely be welcome on a better MVVM approach!